# The following C code shows that there is an undefined reference to 'ext'

Tags: c, linker

The following code shows that there is an undefined reference to 'ext'. I'm not very adept in C. I really need a solution. This issue is present at line 37. Then there are 2 related errors at line 80. One is the one I previously mentioned and the other: "error:1d returned 1 exit status." I keep trying and getting this very same thing. I ask if someone can please kindly assist?

First problem:

```
if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find file! Attempting to create file... \n");

        fptr = fopen("ems.txt","w+");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't create file. Exiting...");
         ext(1);
        }
    }
```

Second problem:

```
case 5:
                puts("Exit was chosen");
                ext(1);
                break;
```

Structure here:

```
struct employee
{
        char name[50];
        char sex;
        char adrs[50];
        char dsgn[25];
        int age,empID;
        float slry;
};
```

Entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "struct.h"

void insert();
void list();
void edit();
void del();
void ext();

FILE * fptr, *ftemp;
struct employee e;
long int recsize;
char empname[50];



int main()
{
    int choice;
    fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "r+");


    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't find file! Attempting to create file... \n");

        fptr = fopen("ems.txt","w+");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Can't create file. Exiting...");
         ext(1);
        }
    }

    //Explain the reason for this?
    //recsize = (long int) sizeof(e);//


    while(1)
    {
        printf("*******************************\n");
        printf("\nEmployee management system");
        printf("\n1. Insert employee information");
        printf("\n2. List all employee information");
        printf("\n3. Edit employee information");
        printf("\n4. Delete employee information");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        printf("\n\n*****************************\n");
        printf("\n\n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                puts("Insert was chosen");
                insert();

                break;
            case 2:
                puts("List was chosen");
                list();
                break;
            case 3:
                puts("Edit was chosen");
                edit();
                break;
            case 4:
                puts("Delete was chosen");
                del();
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Exit was chosen");
                ext(1);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Choice is incorrect!!");
                continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void insert()
{
    char next;

    do
    {
        printf("********************************************************** \n");
        printf("\nEnter the name of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.name, sizeof(e.name), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the sex of the employee (M/m or F/f): ");
        fgets(&e.sex, sizeof(e.sex), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter the address of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.adrs, sizeof(e.adrs), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter designation of the employee: ");
        fgets(e.dsgn, sizeof(e.dsgn), stdin);
        printf("\nEnter age of the employee: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.age);
        printf("\nEnter basic salary of the employee: ");
        scanf("%f", &e.slry);
        printf("\nEnter the employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &e.empID);
        fputs(e.name, fptr);
        fputs(&e.sex, fptr);
        fputs(e.adrs, fptr);
        fputs(e.dsgn, fptr);
        fprintf(fptr, "%d \n%f \n%d \n", e.age, e.slry, e.empID);
       // fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fptr);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDo you want to input more? (y/n): ");
        next = getche();
        printf("\n");


    }
    while(next !='n');

    fclose(fptr);
}

void list ()
{
    /* what is going on here??? */
    while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr)==1)
    {
        printf("\n%s %c %s %s %d %.2f %d",e.name,e.sex,e.adrs,e.dsgn,e.age,e.slry,e.empID);
    }

    getche();
    return ;
}

void edit ()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the employee name to be edited: ");
        scanf("%s", empname);
        while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr)==1)
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nEnter new name,sex,address,designation,age,salary,employee ID ");
                scanf("%s %c %s %s %d %f %d",e.name,&e.sex,e.adrs,e.dsgn,&e.age,&e.slry,&e.empID);
                fseek(fptr,-recsize,SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fptr);
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nEdit another record(y/n)");
        next = getche();
        fflush(stdin);

    }
    while(next != 'n');


    return ;
}

void del()
{
    char next;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter name of employee to delete: ");
        scanf("%s",empname);
        ftemp = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");
        while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fptr) == 1)
        {
            if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)
            {
                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ftemp);
            }
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        fclose(ftemp);
        remove("ems.txt");
        rename("Temp.dat","ems.txt");
        fptr = fopen("ems.txt", "rb+");
        printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
        fflush(stdin);
        next = getche();


    }while(next !='n');
}
```

Comment: BTW, `C#` tag is not the same as `c`

Comment: By chance do you have the file **ems.txt** open in another program?

Comment: Tip: Use `char*` in your structures. Using fixed-length character buffers is usually a bad plan as they're often too short, or way too long. 50 characters might sound like enough for a name, but you'll have five letter names, and seventy letter names in practice.

Comment: If by `ext(1)` do you mean [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit)?

Comment: No, I don't have it open in another.

Comment: Yes, I mean exit(). But I did put ext()

Comment: `fopen("ems.txt", "r+")` This assumes `ems.txt` is in the current directory when the program is run (which is not necessarily the same as the directory of the executable itself). `ext(1);` If that's the library function then it should be `exit(1);`, else if it's your function you need to define it somewhere.

Comment: Okay I find the "char*" interesting. So if I put "char*" that means I don't have to include a range like 50, i.e, "char* 50?"

Comment: If you mean `exit()` then why are you putting in `ext()`? You can't just arbitrarily change the function names. If you want to wrap `exit()` and add additional behaviour then you're obligated to define the function.

Comment: I changed ext to exit and the program's now running. Thank you. But do I have to include a range once I have " char* ?" For e.g, " char* 50." And I have another issue. When I run and select my insert function, it's skipping the sex section.

Comment: Another problem is fine, but open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've posted an [mcve]?  You declare `void ext();`, which is equivalent to `void ext(int)`, which is how you should have declared it, because the old empty `()` form predates the standards (it's ancient) and causes no end of confusions.  So you've declared it, but you have not defined it anywhere.  If it were `extern void ext(int)`, then you would not get the compiler error, but you would probably get a linker error, as you haven't written the `ext` function and the linker won't be able to find it.

If you really intended to use the stdlib function `exit`, then you should remove the `void ext()` declaration and recompile.

---

Update related to additional comments entered while I was distractedly entering the above:

This is just an FYI.  You can create aliases for function names, using preprocessor macros:

```
#define ext(errorCode) exit(errorCode)
```